# Malloc all available memory for a hash table

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, hashtable

I want to construct a hash table that's as large as reasonably possible on a machine. I was thinking that at initialization time I would claim a large block of memory for use by the hash table, but it's not clear to me what the best way to do this is.  I have various thoughts and questions listed below. There are many related posts here on Stack Overflow, but I would still appreciate your thoughts.

Let's say I have 16GiB of RAM to play with.

1. Just pick a number like 8GiB and always allocate that much, and hope that the rest of the system can make do with the rest. If I choose to do this, what's the best way to get hold of 8GiB? It's a 64-bit system so I can call `malloc(1<<33)` and it might work, but that's large enough that I would think fragmentation might be a problem. So would I be best to allocate 8 separate blocks of 1GiB?
2. Rather than picking a number, I would like to just claim all/most of the remaining physical memory. I had naively thought I could just call `malloc` until it returns `NULL`, but optimistic memory allocation makes it very unhelpful (it seems to let me allocate all of my hard drive too). Utilities like `top` and `vmstat` let me query memory usage, are there system calls I can use to get the same information?
3. Am I right to only want physical memory for this purpose? I have never used `mmap` before, should I consider it for constructing a *huge* hash table? My instinct was that random access across the whole table would be bad for `mmap`.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I think it would be better to make a `mmap`: kernel would allocate memory itself and will use it better. BTW, that's possible that your `malloc` won't return NULL, but when you'll try to use that memory you'll get an error.

Comment: A modern operating system isn't going to bother with a definitive separation of physical memory vs. virtual memory to a user-mode program. There are no guarantees the OS won't swap out anything you think is physical-paged memory anytime it needs RAM for other purposes. Some OSs system calls will let you allocate specific-purposed memory, but  anything that does so is entirely system-specific. If you don't think that is a consideration, assume for a moment you can run *two* instances of your program. Think about that a moment. How much "memory" will the *second* process get by your logic?

Comment: what is length of your hash-key(in bytes)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Can't he lock the page into memory? I'm not suggesting that is a good approach, but it is possible.

Perhaps the OP should look at the MAP_HUGETLB (since Linux 2.6.32) option?

For the OP, I ask why do you think you need to allocate so much memory up front? It's generally much saner to start off with something suitably sized and then double, triple, or quadruple your allocation size each time you hit the limit. You should look at some of the NoSQL solutions which are entirely in memory, their core allocation routines should be quite educational.

Comment: @EricUrban he can, and such provisions are usually offered in one way or another on most OS's, but such specificity of locking is system specific; `malloc()` simply isn't going to get you there. Things like `mmap()` can get you closer, but even that is not universal. Windows, for example has its own entirely unique system API for dealing with the nuances of locking physical pages of RAM. But you are correct that there are some "common" ways to get close, just no silver bullet.

Comment: Why do you want to / think you have to do this?

Comment: @EricUrban - without root privileges or at least *assigned* privileges (limits), I doubt user-space code could mlock this much memory.

Comment: from the mlock man page: "Since Linux 2.6.9, no limits are placed on the amount of memory that a privileged process can lock and the RLIMIT_MEMLOCK soft resource limit instead defines a limit on how much memory an unprivileged process may lock."

Comment: @EricUrban I know a normal approach is to reallocate when the hash table is loaded. In this case I already know I'm going to use it all. I know the linux platform it will be running on, so using OS-specific features is OK. Some experiments I ran today suggest `mlock` is not going to work, but `mmap` may be the right option.

Comment: @MichaelMcLoughlin If you are going to use 'all' the memory I suggest just allocating a number of fixed sized chunks up to near the limit and using that. How big should each chunk be? I don't know. You'll have to tune it. Inevitably, some of it gets paged. You can set the swappiness down on the system to help with that.

Answer (score -2):

even if you have sufficient RAM in your system still 8GB is big memory to allocate using malloc.

i suggest you to use paging and splitting concept here.

initially allocate 256MB of memory using malloc , now divide this 256MB into 4K blocks and assign each block with unique page index so that you can access that using the unique page index.

when the page gets full with entries split the page and allocate another 4k block for new page with different page index. keep on doing this rather than allocating all memory at one time.

Comment: Then why allocate 256MB upfront? With your algorithm he'd have to move the data around anyway.

Comment: @LtWolf.....according to me thats the viable solution...256MB is well less than 8GB..and once one of the page is full...he can save it on ondisk memory to vacate the page..this way at anytime 256MB of heap will be used at any time..i believe thats acceptable.....give it reconsideration.

Comment: Moving memory around is slow, the whole point of allocating a lot of memory in advance is to avoid moving it later. And he doesn't want to use the disk apparently so I will disregard that part of your comment.